# what does __block mean in Apple doc sample code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

When read NotificationCenter document, I found the sample code below. What I want to clarify is what does __block mean here? I know when using __block variable can change in block, but token doesn't changed.

```
    NSNotificationCenter * __weak center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    id __block token = [center addObserverForName:@"OneTimeNotification"
                                           object:nil
                                            queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                       usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                           NSLog(@"Received the notification!");
                                           [center removeObserver:token];
                                       }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows to use `token` within block of initialization construction, indicating that its value will be changed later, so can be used in block.

Otherwise you get as below.

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

> I know when using __block variable can change in block, but token doesn't changed.

`__block` shares the variable between all the blocks that capture it, as well as the outside scope where it is declared. It is not only useful when you need to modify the variable inside the block, but also when you modify the variable outside the block and want the changes to be visible in the block.

That is what is happening here. The entire right side of the `=`, including the creation of the lambda and the method call, happen first, and then afterwards the result is assigned to the `token` variable. `token` is captured by the lambda when the lambda is created, which happens before you assign to `token`. So if the lambda just captures the value of `token`, it will always have the value of `token` at the point it captured it (before the assignment), which is `nil`.

`token` is assigned a value in the outside scope after `token` is captured by the lambda. In order for the lambda to see this new value of `token`, the variable must be shared between the scopes, with `__block`.